# Changing JLabel Icon after condition

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

How can I make the change of an existing JLabel with Null ICON to a certain icon after a set of conditions... My logic was for sure clear, but maybe my sintaxis is the problem, please aid.

```
    if(n==true){
    trofeo1.setIcon(trofeo.png);
    }
```

My JLabel is trofeo1, n is just an example of my logic..

Thanks!

Comment: With such a small snippet of code we can't tell much, but I'm assuming you are probably "doing everything" in the graphics thread, and so it never gets a chance to redraw with the new icon (just a guess)

Comment: That Jlabel yea, was made on the graphics thread... there is no chance to change it with conditions?

Comment: Yet another `== true` condition :) Note that, with a boolean expression you don't need `== true`, the expression speaks for itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, try this:

```
if (n == true) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            trofeo1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("trofeo.png"));
        }
    });
}
```

Maybe you can check first the image file is right by doing something like this:

```
File f = new File("trofeo.png");
if (f.exists()) {
} else {
}
```

This is because many times the problem is the image location.

Then, you say "maybe my sintaxis is the problem...", does your code compile? Have you put a breakpoint at `trofeo1.setIcon()` line and check this line is executed? I assume the answer to these two questions is true.

Regards,

Comment: Just tried, the path is fine, image still wont show after condition... :(

Comment: Ok, I will edit my answer to check more posibilities ;)

Comment: Yes, it compiles and everything, it doesnt  even mark  error when the condition is true, its like its avoiding the line even when its true.

Comment: Ok, I suggest you that first, remove the if condition, to know if the matter is in the condition or in the icon setting. This way the icon should be shown always, so the problem would be in the condition. Try it and if it not show like this, reply again

Comment: Yea, I have other things running via that condition, and all of them work... so the condition is not the problem :S  Here is the whole condition set up

Comment: Ok, I will make one last attempt ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to refresh your JLabel with the method `repaint()`?

```
 if(n==true){
    trofeo1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("trofeo.png"));
    trofeo1.repaint();
 }
```

This method is an update of the component's display.

Comment: just tried, not worked :( I might go to create a new JFrame to show the image, but for real, thats my last option.

Comment: also tried the `validate()` function 
If it still does not work, check what happens with a debugger (eclipse's debugger for example)

Answer (score 0):

For those who end up here, yea, MY LINK or path to the photo was wrong, just go look for the photo location throught your carpets, copy the url and it will be ready to go. Here is an example....

C:\Users\Beto\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoFinal\src\proyectofinal\trofeo.png

Thanks to all who tried to help!

Final code

```
if(n==true){
trofeo1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\Users\Beto\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProyectoFinal\src\proyectofinal\trofeo.png"));
trofeo1.repaint();
}
```